# Event Button.GotFocus isn't fired

Tags: vb.net, focus

I have the below code to change background color when a button gets focus:

```
Private Sub Btn_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_ShowSummary.GotFocus, Btn_ToolTip.GotFocus, Btn_ShowHideTbl.GotFocus
    If CType(sender, Button).Name = "Btn_ShowHideTbl" Then Stop 'Here never stops
    If CType(sender, Button).Name = "Btn_ToolTip" Then Stop 'Here stops
    CType(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_ShowSummary.LostFocus, Btn_ToolTip.LostFocus, Btn_ShowHideTbl.LostFocus
    If CType(sender, Button).Name = "Btn_ShowHideTbl" Then Stop 'Here stops!!
    CType(sender, Button).BackColor = Me.BackColor
End Sub
```

As shown in the commented code the color changes only for two of the three buttons.

I added some code to intercept when `Btn_ShowHideTbl.GotFocus` is fired but the code never stopped on this.
So I added other code to intercept when `Btn_ToolTip.GotFocus` is fired and the code was stopped on this.
Then I add other code to intercept when `Btn_ShowHideTbl.LostFocus` is fired and the code was stopped on this.

I want to point out that the only other code for `Btn_ShowHideTbl` is on click event.

I can't figure what's happening.

**EDIT**
I tried removing and re-adding the button and I noticed that `Btn_ShowHideTbl` was automatically removed from `Handles` in the sub `LostFocus` while it was underlined with red in `Handles` of the sub `GotFocus`.

I don't know what it means but there is something wrong in this

**EDIT 2**
After 3 cut/paste of button and code, the code is working.
It could be some bug of automation of Visual Studio...

Comment: Of course you have checked and rechecked that the name is correct, right?

Comment: @Steve I typed it using intellisense, copied and pasted, and so on...

Comment: How do you set the focus to the button? Using the Keyboard Tab or the Mouse click?

Comment: Did you have the TabStop property set to True?

Comment: @Steve Yes It's all right. After 3 cut/paste of button and code, the code is working. It could be some bug of automation of Visual Studio

Comment: Never use Got/LostFocus, always Enter and Leave.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, can you explain me why?

Comment: It is a long and boring story.  That the events are hidden in the designer and you therefore somewhat inevitably have trouble getting them subscribed is a strong enough cue.